# Getting multiple Apple IDs

Tags: apple-id

Is it possible to have multiple Apple IDs?

Can I have different Apple Ids using my different email ids?

Comment: Whats the advantage to having more than one Apple ID ? Isnt it best to stick with one for life ?

Comment: @bmike Did you mean to close this - it has concise correct answers - prohaps you meant protect but the new answer is better than others

Comment: Yes @Mark It's not going to need any new answers at this poin since we've got three versions of yes and in 7 years no one wants to say No.  We can discuss this in a question on [meta] why this has issues as a yes/no unclear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Anthony Green's reply as you can have multiple Apple Accounts. But as of this time I would recommend against it as you can't merge account purchases to one account. So if you're going to use the upcoming iCloud service you can only sync one account with it, so anything on the second account that you have purchased will not sync.

Hopefully Apple will allow you to sync account purchases from multiple accounts to one master account in the future but who knows, sigh...

Comment: If I get one Apple ID with my email id, can't i later change the email identification of the same ID?

Comment: you can change the email the alerts get sent to but the email used with the Apple Id will be the same. So if you register with phill@apple.com as your Apple Id, you can always change your email notifications to phill@other.com but your Apple Id is still phill@apple.com. You can still open another Apple Id with phill@other.com but then all of your purchases with phill@apple.com wont transfer to the new Id so you will have two Apple Id's

Comment: i think it's possible now to change at appleid.apple.com, there's an edit field for the Primary Email Address; i haven't tested this.

Comment: you can change your email address not Apple id

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an Apple ID is per email address, so you can have multiple Apple IDs in the same store, or different store.

Answer (score 3):

Having 2 Apple ID's is possible. Go to the [AppleID website](https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create) and create an new apple ID by filling in the requested information. You will most likely need to use an email not registered to an Apple ID yet, and possibly a phone number as well.

You may use one apple ID to sync to your icloud, and your second Apple ID to log into all of your Apple Purchases and Store accounts i.e. iTunes, iBooks, etc. The above users are right, in that you can not merge these two accounts. However, you can turn on "family sharing" to link these accounts, in order to share purchased apps accross each account.